# spring-boot actuator refresh and in memory db

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

Is there a way to somehow configure spring-boot (2.1.1) actuator refresh or hikari/datasource so it reexecutes logic responsible for inmemory database (h2 for instance) creation?
At the moment after the /actuator/refresh I do not have previously created tables (hbm2ddl: create-drop or hbm2ddl: create) anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sample code of your implementation.
But Your problem seems to be not a problem as this is how the In-Memory Dbs are supposed to work.
These Dbs(H2,Hsql) are used for testing and not prefered for production but if you need for some small data than these are absolutely fine.
Also,
 `(hbm2ddl: create-drop or hbm2ddl: create)`

Here, with this it will always recreate the db after the service is restarted.
change it to 
 `(hbm2ddl: update)` *The syntax might not be correct*.

*Also taking into consideration you are using hibernate*

Answer (score 0):

I think actuator is meant for different things, to get an understanding of what happens in a microservice instance in a runtime mainly.

```
/actuator/refresh
```

indeed manages beans with Refresh Scope, it just recreates them without recreating the whole application context (which can be an expensive operation) if the configurations have changed (like in spring boot cloud config service).

So it has nothing to do with the lifecycle of H2 DataSource which is indeed used mainly for tests as our colleague Shubham has kindly stated, and and this makes the question even more confusing :)